# Add subdirectory of application to autoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have under my /application folder a folder named "grids". Now my classnames are App_Grid_CustomGrid. How can I autoload these classes under the grids folder? I have tried the follow code in index.php before the Zend_Application. But it didn't work. The code couldn't find the CustomGrid class.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader/Resource.php';

$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => '',
));
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('grid', 'grids', 'Grid');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following method in Bootstrap.ini to autoload custom classes stored in a folder in my application root (customised to suit your needs):

```
protected function _initNamespaces()
{        
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => '',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
                'grid' => array(
                    'path'      => 'grids/',
                    'namespace' => 'Grid',
                ),
                'example' => array(
                    'path'      => 'example_folder/',
                    'namespace  => 'Example'
                )
    ));        
}
```

Leaving the namespace blank allows for the you to omit `App_` from the start of your class names. I do this as seperately, I use `App_` in the Library folder for custom Classes and Plugins. Multiple namespaces can be loaded using the above method, you just add additional arrays to the `resourcesType` argument.

The application structure looks like this:

```
|Project
    |-Application
        |-grids
            |-Test.php
        |-configs
        |-controllers
        |-models
        |-views
        |-Bootstrap.php
    |-Docs
    |-Library
    |-Public
    |-.zfproject.xml
```

Test.php would look like this:

```
<?php
class Grid_Test
{

    /**
     * Return sum of two variables
     *
     * @param  int $x
     * @param  int $y
     * @return array
     */
    public function add($x, $y)
    {
        return  $x + $y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to write this Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource line for each module?

Comment: No. The above example of Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource allows you to tell your application to register an array of namespaces - you can then use in custom classes. I've updated the example with 'example' to illustrate how you'd add additional namespaces to the call.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
    'namespace' => 'App',
));
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('grid', 'grids/', 'Grid');
```

I think it wasn't working because it needs the namespace since it is prefixed with `App_`, and there was no trailing slash on the end of the directory so it may have been looking for `gridsCustomGrid.php` as well.